# Finding numbers that cannot be paired

Tags: python

I've a function which aim is to find numbers that you cannot pair with others. If a number cannot be paired up with another identical number, then you will have to return it.

example:

```
[1,1,1,1, 2, 3, 4]
```

expected result:

```
[2,3,4]
```

```
def pair(input):
    while len(input) > 2:
        for i in range(len(input) - 1):
            for j in range(len(input) - 1):
                print(input)
                if input[i] == input[j]:
                    input.pop(i)
                    input.pop(j)
                    print(input)
                else:
                    break
            
        return input


print(pair([1,1,1,1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Comment: What about `[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4]`?

Comment: What is your question? You didn't ask any.

Comment: Is the input always sorted, or is that just a bad example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this problem is to find the unique elements in the list, and if an element occurs an odd number of times the in the list, returned it.

```
def pair(lst):
    set_lst = set(lst)
    output = []
    for elem in set_lst:
        if lst.count(elem) % 2 != 0:
            output.append(elem)
    return output


print(pair([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can use a library, you could use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from collections, and just return the values in the list that have an odd count (since that implies there is one of those numbers that cannot be paired with another):

```py
from collections import Counter

ll = [ 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
c = Counter(ll)
[num for num, cnt in c.items() if cnt % 2 == 1]
```

Output:

```
[2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Keeping track of the numbers that occurred an odd number of times:

```
def pair(lst):
    odd = set()
    for x in lst:
        odd ^= {x}
    return list(odd)

print(pair([1,1,1,1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Comment: Best answer on my opinion. Looks like it working even if list is not sorted. Also it returns `[10, 6]` for `[1,1,1,1, 4,4, 6, 10,10,10]` inserted data. It is still correct but order is different. Still can't figure out how it works, can you add some explanation?

Comment: @rzlvmp Yes, it works for unsorted data. And yes, it doesn't preserve order. I assume that's ok since the OP accepted an answer which also doesn't preserve order and because they didn't say anything about order and didn't specify what to do for example for [1,1,2,1]. In that case, depending on *how* you pair up numbers, the result can be [1,2] or [2,1] even if you preserve order. So it seems they don't care about order. My solution works as mentioned above it. I start with an empty set and the `^= {x}` inserts `x` into the set if it's not in the set, and removes it if it *is* in the set.

Comment: oh, I see... You removing element from set if it already exists or adding if it not in set. It is smart and allows us to avoid elements counting. But still not good if input list is sorted, because we have to check if element exists in growing set at every step

Comment: @rzlvmp Yes, if the input were always sorted, then something like yours *might* be a little more efficient. But they didn't say it's sorted and their code suggests it's not (otherwise they'd only compare adjacent elements, not all possible pairs). It looks like their example is just a bad example.

Answer (score 1):

According your example input list is **sorted**. In this case @KetZoomer's solution is not effective, because it searching for the `elem` in whole list and counting it every time (`lst.count(elem)`)

If you counted number of `1`'s you don't need to search for `2` in whole list from `0`th element to last element again.

You should to use something like this:

```py
def pairs(lst: list) -> list:
  if len(lst) > 0:
    # set first element
    current_el = lst[0]
    duplicate_count = 1
    values_without_pair = []
  else:
    return []

  # loop for elements starting from 2nd
  for i in range(1, len(lst)):
    # if looped element same as stored in memory increase count and go to next element
    if current_el == lst[i]:
      duplicate_count += 1
    # if element is changed then check count value is even or not
    # and set new element for checking
    else:
      if duplicate_count % 2 != 0:
        values_without_pair.append(current_el)
      duplicate_count = 1
      current_el = lst[i]

  # process last element
  if duplicate_count % 2 != 0:
    values_without_pair.append(current_el)

  return values_without_pair


print(pairs([1,1,1,1,2,3,4]))
```

Comment: Raising that exception is just wrong.

Comment: Actually it depends on what inserted list have to be, but yes, in current description saying nothing about non allowed empty lists. So I removed exception

Comment: Better, but still the correct result is simply an empty list as output. Just like for input [1,1], for example. Imagine you're a *user* of that function and the function normally gives you a list of ints but in one case gives you a string so you need to write special code to handle that string... Ugh... Frustrating.

Comment: Btw it would be good if this were written as a function, like the OP's. Would be cleaner and more useful, for example for testing multiple inputs and for testing alongside other solutions for correctness and speed.

Comment: Haha, you are a strict teacher :-)). Yeah, I understand what you trying to say

Comment: Oh, another rather mportant thing: Don't modify the input (your pop does) unless that's what the function should do.

Comment: Ah frack... 80% through writing a testing program with our solutions I accidentally refreshed the page and it's gone... Might try again later.